# RGLPK constraints issue

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization, glpk

I have an optimization problem that is providing some issues.

When I run the following code, I get an optimal solution.

```
objective <- DK$DK.proj

objective.variable.types <- rep("B", length(DK$player))
constraint.matrix <- rbind(as.numeric(DK$pos == "SP"),
                       as.numeric(DK$pos == "C"),
                       as.numeric(DK$pos == "1B"),
                       as.numeric(DK$pos == "2B"),
                       as.numeric(DK$pos == "SS"),
                       as.numeric(DK$pos == "3B"),
                       as.numeric(DK$pos == "OF"),
                       DK$salary)
constraint.directions <- c(
"==", # SP
"==", # C
"==", # 1B
"==", # 2B
"==", # SS
"==", # 3B
"==", # OF,
"<=") # max salary

rhs <- c(
2, # SP
1, # C
1, # 1B
1, # 2B
1, # SS
1, # 3B
3, # OF
50000) # max salary

Rglpk_solve_LP(obj = objective, mat = constraint.matrix, dir = constraint.directions, rhs = rhs,
                  types = objective.variable.types, max = TRUE)
```

But the issue is some players in the data frame are duplicated because they have multiple positions. There is 2 rows of the same player, with just a different position column, but I can only use each player once. So I added the following constraint in.

```
objective <- DK$DK.proj

objective.variable.types <- rep("B", length(DK$player))
constraint.matrix <- rbind(as.numeric(DK$pos == "SP"),
                         as.numeric(DK$pos == "C"),
                         as.numeric(DK$pos == "1B"),
                         as.numeric(DK$pos == "2B"),
                         as.numeric(DK$pos == "SS"),
                         as.numeric(DK$pos == "3B"),
                         as.numeric(DK$pos == "OF"),
                         DK$salary,
                         n_distinct(DK$player))
constraint.directions <- c(
"==", # SP
"==", # C
"==", # 1B
"==", # 2B
"==", # SS
"==", # 3B
"==", # OF,
"<=", # max salary
"==") # max players

rhs <- c(
2, # SP
1, # C
1, # 1B
1, # 2B
1, # SS
1, # 3B
3, # OF
50000, # max salary
10) # max players



Rglpk_solve_LP(obj = objective, mat = constraint.matrix, dir = constraint.directions, rhs = rhs,
             types = objective.variable.types, max = TRUE)
```

And now I cannot get a feasible solution. Any suggestions on what I should change the constraint to so that I can always have 10 unique, non-duplicated players, while following the other constraints?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your constraint matrix isn't doing what you think it is. If look at the constraint matrix you coded, you'll see that the bottom row consists of all entries equal to the number of unique players in the DK data frame. The linear programming constraint must be achieved when the constraint matrix is multiplied by the solution vector. A single 1 in the solution vector and the resulting entry after the matrix multiplication will be the number of total unique players. So the constraint cannot be achieved and it doesn't converge.

Here is a hack that will work. It isn't pretty, but it gets the job done.

```
objective <- DK$DK.proj
playerMatrix <- lapply(unique(DK$player), function(name) as.numeric(DK$player==name))
playerMatrix <- t(matrix(unlist(playerMatrix), ncol=n_distinct(DK$player)))

objective.variable.types <- rep("B", length(DK$player))
constraint.matrix <- rbind(as.numeric(DK$pos == "SP"),
                           as.numeric(DK$pos == "C"),
                           as.numeric(DK$pos == "1B"),
                           as.numeric(DK$pos == "2B"),
                           as.numeric(DK$pos == "SS"),
                           as.numeric(DK$pos == "3B"),
                           as.numeric(DK$pos == "OF"),
                           DK$salary,
                           playerMatrix)
constraint.directions <- c(
  "==", # SP
  "==", # C
  "==", # 1B
  "==", # 2B
  "==", # SS
  "==", # 3B
  "==", # OF,
  "<=", # max salary
  rep("<=", nrow(playerMatrix))) # unique players

rhs <- c(
  2, # SP
  1, # C
  1, # 1B
  1, # 2B
  1, # SS
  1, # 3B
  3, # OF
  50000, # max salary
  rep(1, nrow(playerMatrix))) # unique players

  sol <- Rglpk_solve_LP(obj = objective, mat = constraint.matrix, 
           dir = constraint.directions, rhs = rhs,
           types = objective.variable.types, max = TRUE)
```

The player matrix has the same number of rows as unique players and keeps track of ensuring that no unique player is selected more than once.